# Confirm the nested webelement presence with xpath (Selenium Webdriver)

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

So this is the HTML design, and I'm trying to see if the **`<i class="fas fa-lock"></i>`** is displayed for the particular text "Good luck Harry".

How to identify multiple webelements with xpath?

I can use xpath to identify these webelements individually but how to make sure they are nested?

```
 <div class="card">

  <div class="overlayBg">   

   <div class="duration_notif">22:33</div>
     <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
   </div>

   <div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-title">
      <div class="LinesEllipsis  ">
        <div>Good luck Harry</div>
      </div>
     </h5>
   </div>
</div>
```

There are two webelements that I need to verify if they are kinda nested within each other.

I'm using pagefactory and selenium with Java.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you provide examples for what you want and what you not want?

Comment: @swame_sp `<i class="fas">` is the child of `<div class="overlayBg">`, how can `<i class="fas">` (actually `<i class="fas fa-lock">`) be nested with `<div>Good luck Harry</div>`?

Comment: @zx485, the existing text did not display correctly, fixed it now.

Comment: @DebanjanB, both have a common parent, div class card. So wondering how to combine if the `<i>`class is displayed for the text `good luck harry`.

Comment: @swame_sp IMO, we can easily work for a `single_parent`-`single_child` relation but not sure about `single_parent`-`multiple_child`relation.

Answer (score 2):

Nested in the sense `<div>Good luck Harry</div>` is a child of the other `div`, which is a child of the `h5`, which is a child of the `<div class="card-body">`?

```
//div[@class="card-body"]/h5[@class="card-title"]/div[contains (@class, "LinesEllipsis")]/div
```

In xpath the `/` denotes direct descendance - the node must be 1st level child of the other one.
When you use this xpath to work with the element, by the fact that it is found you will guarantee it has this ancestor structure.

Nested in the sense `<div class="overlayBg">` and `<div class="card-body">` have a common parent - that `div`?

```
/div//div[@class="card-body" and preceding-sibling::div[@class="overlayBg"]]/h5[@class="card-title"]/div[contains (@class, "LinesEllipsis")]/div
```

You would start off the common parent, and extend the predicate with `preceding-sibling` axis - which means "there must be a node on the same level, that matches this condition"; and being on the same level, this would mean the two share their parent node.

Comment: Yes this worked, by going one level higher (above div class card) and coming down with a common branch for both the nodes.

`//div[contains(@class,'stress')]//div[following-sibling::div[@class='card-body']//div/div[contains(.,'Good luck harry')]]/div/i[@class='fas fa-lock']`